# Render field as read only using the Grails Fields Plugin

Tags: grails

Using the Fields plugin:

```
<f:field bean="operator" property="defaultPaymentMethod"/>
```

Renders nicely with a label "Default Payment Method" and input box.

How can I (what is the best way) show the field and not allow the user to change the value?

- f:display only shows the value, with no label.
- I tried writing a wrapper like this:

  `<div class="fieldcontain required"><label for="${property}">
  <g:message
          code="${entityName}.${property}.label"
          default="${property}"/>
  <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
  </label><g:field type="text"
               name="${property}"
               readonly="readonly"
               value="${value}"/>
  </div>`

but that didn't come out with the nice label formatting.

Is there a way to make a field read only with the Grails Fields plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Use f:display to show only the value:

```
<f:display bean="operator" property="defaultPaymentMethod"/>
```

If you still want to keep the look of an input-field, you can use the attribute: disabled="true" in the f:field tag.

EDIT:
"disabled="true" in the f:field tag" is not working

Comment: In the interests of some lazy development and letting the fields plugin do the formatting, yes, I do want to keep the look of an input field. Tried using disabled="true" and it had no impact. The fields were still editable. Couldn't find a "disabled" property in the documentation.

Comment: I see... you are right. disabled true seems not to work in current version... Not a real solution, but working, is to use jquery. (<script>$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#defaultPaymentMethod').attr('readonly', true)
        });
        </script>).